# how can convert date to time span in lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

i have the code below.

```
        var StartdateHsrch = DateTime.Parse(checklistReport.StartdateHsrch).Ticks;
        var EnddateHsrch = DateTime.Parse(checklistReport.EnddateHsrch).Ticks;

        var reportResult = _context.ChecklistReports.Where(e =>
            e.RequestDateGregorianHsrch.Value.Ticks >= StartdateHsrch &&
            e.RequestDateGregorianHsrch.Value.Ticks <= EnddateHsrch
        ).ToList();

        return reportResult;
```

but i get this error in runtime:

could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information

**please help me how can i change date with ticks?**

Comment: Do you really need to work with ticks? You are getting this error because this query will be translated to SQL and there is no explicit implementation of DateTime conversion to Ticks

Comment: Can it be that `e.RequestDateGregorianHsrch` has no value at runtime?

Comment: Why the requirement for `Ticks`, just compare the actual `DateTime` values

Comment: You can filter using DateTime in lambda and execute the query, then filter the returned result using TimeSpan if necessary.